# How to find out what is preventing my Node JS application from shutting down naturally?

Tags: javascript, node.js, shutdown

I have developed a `node.js` application. Yet, at some stage, the application should shutdown naturally. I can see that it reaches the final instruction through a `console.log()` message.

However, Netbeans tells me it is still running. There is something keeping the application alive, although I am end my connections to my database. I am running out of ideas.

How can I find out what is preventing my application from shutting down?

**UPDATE**

Here is the list of modules I use:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "0.9",
    "body-parser": "1.4.3",
    "clean-css": "2.1.8",
    "cookie": "0.1.2",
    "cookie-parser": "1.1.0",
    "crypto-js": "3.1.2-3",
    "csurf": "1.2.0",
    "emailjs": "0.3.6",
    "express-session": "1.2.1",
    "express": "4.3.1",
    "html-minifier": "0.6.1",
    "markup-js": "1.5.18",
    "node-fs": "0.1.7",
    "node-fs-extra": "0.8.1",
    "pem": "1.4.1",
    "pg": "3.2.0",
    "readdirp": "1.0.1",
    "st": "0.4.1",
    "utils-merge": "1.0.0",
    "validator": "3.12.0",
    "yuicompressor": "2.4.8"
  }
```

Comment: Could you please give us more details? Which OS are you running? Does this happen in a normal shell too or only in Netbeans? Is there any exception thrown during shutdown? What is your application doing? You say "` end my connections to my database`" - which database library are you using, which further libs are part of this application?

Comment: Windows 7. Netbeans calls node. No exception thrown. It is running unit tests mostly. I use node pg to access a PostGreSql database. See my question update for the list of modules I use.

Comment: And when running it directly from the console, the program finishes normally? Are you calling it through an action config in Netbeans or through Maven, Ant etc. or custom Unit-Test runner in a foreign language like Java? I can see `express` in your dependencies: is your script running a server that might wait for responses?

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of undocumented functions that can help you determine this somewhat: `process._getActiveRequests()` and `process._getActiveHandles()`. They both return an array of active requests (e.g. network requests) and active handles(/file descriptors) respectively.

In node v0.11+ there is a new (documented) API called [AsyncListener](http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.11.13/docs/api/tracing.html#tracing_async_listeners) which may also help you track asynchronous requests.

Comment: I can see one active request and 6 active handles. How can I find more info about them and how can I kill them?

Answer (score 0):

The most common problem I've found is that you have timeouts that have not executed. Since clearing those is not always practical, you may need to force quit your program with:

```
process.exit(0)
```